# Determine the SharePoint Application Pool Account Using Sharepoint API?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-api

Is there a way of determining the user login used for the Application Pool identity using the SharePoint API?

Thanks, MagicAndi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [article](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2009/05/18/recoverfetch-the-application-pool-password.aspx) gives a very useful code snippet to get the application pool identity's username:

```
string sAppPoolUsername = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.ApplicationPool.Username;
```

**Update**
Managed to bring this down to a one-liner, given above.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it - when you run your code with `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`, it is actually executed under the application pool's account. All you have to do is look at `System.Environment.UserName` at that moment.

However, I believe there is a more elegant way to achieve this.

Comment: naivists, Thanks, I had forgotten about the System.Environment.Username option. +1